# Swift 3 Colour Space macOS not IOS

Tags: macos, swift3

How can I convert an RGB image into its grayscaled colour space?  I can find a lot of code for iOS but non for macOS.. And the Apple's documentations are all in objective C....

```
    let width = image.size.width
    let height = image.size.height
    let imageRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height);
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();


    let bits = image.representations.first as! NSBitmapImageRep;
    bitmap!.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: nil)


    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue);
    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue);
    context.draw(image.cgImage!, in : imageRect);// and this line is wrong obviously..
```

This is what I have got so far..just copy and pasting from the internet.. but I have no idea on how to go further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an interesting way to do this.. My code are simply copied from the three sources below.

[how to create grayscale image from nsimage in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409536/how-to-create-grayscale-image-from-nsimage-in-swift)

[Greyscale Image using COCOA and NSImage](http://richintellectcodingtips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/greyscale-image-using-cocoa-and-nsimage.html)

[Changing the Color Space of NSImage: The second reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253521/changing-the-color-space-of-nsimage/34045661?noredirect=1#comment71262512_34045661)

My Code:

```
func saveImage(image:NSImage, destination:URL) throws{
    let rep = greyScale(image);
    var data = rep.representation(using: NSJPEGFileType, properties: [:]);
    try data?.write(to: destination);

}

// rgb2gray
func greyScale(image: NSImage) -> NSBitmapImageRep{
    let w = image.size.width
    let h = image.size.height
    let imageRect : NSRect! = NSMakeRect(0,0, w, h);
    let colourSpace : ColourSpace! = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    let context : CGContext! = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(w), 
                                        height: Int(h), bitsPerComponent: 8, 
                                        bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, 
                                        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue);        

    context.draw(nsImageToCGImage(image: image), in: imageRect);
    let greyImage : CGImage! = context.makeImage();

    return NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: greyImage);
}


func nsImageToCGImage(image: NSImage) -> CGImage{
    if let imageData = image.tiffRepresentation as NSData! {
        let imageSource : CGImageSource! = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, 
                                        nil);
        let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil);
        return image;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I am still trying to understand the principle behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `CIFilter`. The annoyance is that you have to convert back and forth between `NSImage` and `CIImage`:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreImage

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "jpg")!
let image = CIImage(contentsOf: url)!

let bwFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls", withInputParameters: ["inputImage": image, "inputSaturation": 0.0])!

if let ciImage = bwFilter.outputImage {
    let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: ciImage)
    let nsImage = NSImage(size: rep.size)
    nsImage.addRepresentation(rep)
    // nsImage is now your black-and-white image
}
```

Comment: [Changing the Color Space of NSImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253521/changing-the-color-space-of-nsimage/42042573#42042573) I have found this post teaching how to change colour space. I am on the final masking step.

Comment: The reason why I am trying hard to do it in a proper way is that I've found that Apple's framework has defined some colour spaces. I dont need to worry about the settings in the future for the other colour spaces :)